# Boolean operators, first-class functions

Tags: dafny

It appears that built-in Boolean operators are not first-class functions in Dafny, as the following code doesn't compile. Am I missing something? As a work-around, I assume that we can just wrap built-in functions in our own functions.

```
datatype binOp = X 

function evalOp(o: binOp): bool -> bool
{
    match o
    {
        case X => &&
    }
}
```

The error message, by the way, is "Invalid UnaryExpression".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Dafny does not treat operators like `&&` as function values.

As you guessed, you can wrap the operator to create a function. In your example, something like this might work.

```
case X => (x, y) => x && y
```

If you plan to use the function a lot, you might instead prefer to give it a name.